# Definir mensaje de validacion cuando el tamaño de archivo es mayor al definido en php.ini

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Tengo un campo input.file multiple con name galery.
La regla de validacion para cada uno de los archivos del campo es la siguiente.

```
'galery.*' => "mimes:jpeg,jpg|max:2024"
```

Los mensajes para cada una de dichas reglas:

```
[
   'galery.*.mimes' => 'The Images must be of type: jpg, jpeg',
   'galery.*.max' => 'The Images must be less than 2Mb.'
]
```

En mi php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 4M
```

El problema es el siguiente.
Cuando el tamaño de algun archivo subido es mayor que mi regla de validacion pero menor que el definido en mi php.ini, me lanza el mensaje que establezco para dicha regla.
Pero si el tamaño de algun archivo es mayor que el definido en php.ini, la validacion devuelve otro mensaje:

> "The galery2.0 failed to upload."

Hay alguna forma de definir el mensaje cuando el tamaño excede el de php.ini?

Comment: A lo mejor me equivoco pero en el php.init estas declarando el tamaño maximo de un archivo, y lo que buscas es crear una validacion de que tal archivo no sea mayor a X, por eso falla, lo que yo hice en un proyecto fue crear una validacion yo mismo como aparece en la documentacion de Validations de laravel e importar esa validacion en mi validator, funciono perfecto

Comment: Creo que es lo mismo que tengo hecho. La validacion de laravel me funciona perfecto siempre y cuando el archivo no sobrepase el tamaño declarado en php.ini. Cuando eso pasa el mensaje que devuelve laravel no es el que que yo declaro, sino el que espefique anteriormente. Parece que primero se chechea el tamaño del php.ini y despues las validaciones declaradas a laravel. Pero siempre el mensaje lo devuelve la validacion de laravel porque viene con el formato establecido.

Comment: Tal vez no me equivoque, en php.ini declaras el tamaño maximo a subir a tu server, y con el validator el tamaño maximo permitido a subir a un controlador, por eso si en php.init tienes un maximo por ejemplo de 100mb y el validator es de 150mb vas a obtener un error de servidor y no una excepcion de laravel, intenta dejar el php.ini por defecto y haz todo con el validator y cuentame como te va

Comment: Entiendo lo que planteas, siempre que no se cumpla el maximo permitido del php se lanzara el error del servidor. Realmente lo que necesito es cambiar el mensaje que devuelve laravel sin importar si es por la validacion o por el php.ini.